# CSS Card expand to center of the screen

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-animations, card

I'm making a todo list-like application. I need to make a todo card that will expand on click and move to the center of the sreen without moving other cards in bento board.

Here's a brief example of card. So firstly I need to somehow make ther cartd smaller and hide everything in ticket__body. Then I need to move and expand it on click at card itself. I've already tried using position relative with `transform: translate();` which didn't help me. The animation was laggy and the card was "jumping".

[image]

The actual code of card:

```
.ticket {
  background-color: rgb(25, 25, 25);
  max-width: 300px;
  border-radius: 25px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.ticket__header {
  font-size: 1.1rem;
  font-weight: 800;
}

.ticket__body {
}

.ticket__tag {
  font-weight: 600;
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 110, 230);
  max-width: fit-content;
  border-radius: 1024px;
}

.ticket__text {
  font-weight: 300;
}
```

```
function Ticket() {
  return (
    <div className='ticket'>
      <div className="ticket__header">Lorem ipsum dolor sit.</div>
      <div className="ticket__body">
        <div className="ticket__tag">Emergent</div>
        <div className="ticket__text">Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Asperiores enim assumenda incidunt esse repellat ipsa aliquid cum quam? Eveniet ullam suscipit ducimus eligendi blanditiis! Doloribus.</div>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: You aren't going to get an `onClick` type of event in CSS, you can without style changes, just `display:none` the element you want to hide on load and then on `:hover{display:block}`. If you want an actual, "user clicks button", your best/easiest bet is going to be some simple JS for something like I've described above for toggling visibility

Comment: That functionality can only be added by using JavaScript event handling. The only thing you can do in CSS is make transition smooth or hidden along with some hover effect.

Comment: Ok, I’m not afraid of using js to get on click event obviously. I prefer to add another class selector to my ticket element. How do I move card to the centre of page?

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in css:

```
    .ticket { justify-content: center; }
```

Thanks